# wget: what does this trailing dash represent/do?

Tags: shell, wget

`wget http://ipinfo.io/ip -qO -`

I'm new to `bash` and can't seem to figure out what that trailing dash character does (or why it is required in this command).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Aside: Consider using `curl` rather than wget, which will emit content to stdout by default.

Comment: This has nothing to do with bash. You need to read the documentation for the `wget` command.

Comment: @KeithThompson, agreed that it's nothing to do with bash. OTOH, since this behavior is conformant with POSIX-specified conventions, it's not quite entirely wget-specific.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Thankyou for mentioning that the trailing slashes are POSIX conformant.. I have noted the use of these especially with tarballs like `gzip somestuff | tar -`

Comment: @sjsam, ...now, `tar` is a whole different thing; the POSIX-specified archiver with support for `tar`-compatible archives is actually `pax` when given `-x ustar`; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By convention (which not all programs follow), a dash in filename position refers to stdin or stdout, as appropriate. Since this is an argument to `-O` (output), it refers to stdout.

A more verbose way to write this (on Linux or other operating systems where `/dev/stdout` is usable by programs other than just the shell) would be:

```
wget http://ipinfo.io/ip --quiet --output-document=/dev/stdout
```

---

As it happens, this behavior is defined by the [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html). Specifically:

> Guideline 5:
>   One or more options without option-arguments, followed by at most one option that takes an option-argument, should be accepted when grouped behind one '-' delimiter.

...thus, `-qO` is treated identically to `-q -O`.

> Guideline 13:
>   For utilities that use operands to represent files to be opened for either reading or writing, the '-' operand should be used to mean only standard input (or standard output when it is clear from context that an output file is being specified) or a file named -.

...thus, the behavior regarding `-` is explicitly specified.

Answer (score 3):

To print the output at the STDOUT which is usually your terminal.

> See the manpage for wget which says :
>
> -O file
>          --output-document=file
>              The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is
>   used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling
>   link conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)